# WPF invoke from two threads

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, invoke

I try to invoke twice and then from anther object once more.

```
public void Show()
{
    if (mainGrid == null)
        return;
    if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate() { Show(); }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
        return;
    }

    mainGrid.Children.Add(rec);
    rec.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
    rec.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch;

    mainGrid.Children.Add(this);
    this.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    this.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
}
```

two objects B, C inherit this function from A:
when I call from processes B.show() then B.showStop() from Thread and C.show() I get exception on using privileged  main.children.Add(..) from C.show()
please help me solve this problem.

Comment: I removed the second method declaration as it seemed to be the exact same thing. (Did you paste twice accidentally?)

Comment: What is the actual exception you're getting? And what is the code of `showStop()`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should provide more info on you problem, for example:

- which kind of class is A  (it seems to be an UI object though)
- what is rec

But for the moment i think the problem could be that you're instantiating those visual objects not in the UI Thread: if you create say a Button on a workerthread it will have that thread Dispatcher, which is different from the UI Thread Dispatcher.

I can't exactly tell you what's happening with so little info but i think that you're adding two controls which were created on different threads so one of the two `Add` will give you an exception.